# Discord bot hosting on Glitch.com - Node package issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to host my discord bot on glitch.com. My bot works fine if launched from my personal terminal, the issue on glitch appears to be packages/node related.

this is my package.json

```
    {
  "name": "mudbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "MUDbot",
  "main": "bot.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^13.12.0",
    "env": "^0.0.2",
    "events": "^3.3.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.2",
    "i18next-node-fs-backend": "^2.1.3",
    "node": "^19.0.0",
    "node-events": "^0.0.2",
    "node-fs": "^0.1.7"
  }
}
```

When I run 'node bot.js' on the glitch terminal, I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/rbd/pnpm-volume/d5c775c7-bd94-4b87-abee-5713ace40ae7/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js:3:22)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

I have tried 'npm i', 'npm i discord.js', 'enable-mnpm' over and over but I still get this error. I am not even sure where 'node events' is being used in my code.

EDIT: per the response below, I added `"engines": { "node": "16.6.1" }`
Into my package.json. Which causes this error:

```
    $ npm i discord.js
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by node)
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
```

To which I use 'enable-npm', which then allows me to run it, but if I try to npm anything else, it throws the same error. After 'npm i' and 'npm i discord.js', when I now run 'node .' or 'node bot.js' I get:

```
   $ node bot.js
-su: /app/node_modules/.bin/node: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to set the Node version you want the container to use, as Glitch’s default may not be compatible with what your packages need. See https://help.glitch.com/kb/article/59-can-i-change-the-version-of-node-js-my-project-uses/ and I think setting the Node version to 16.x will stop those errors.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've edited my question with further issues after following the instructions.